# Can syslinux chainload an EFI file?

Tags: bootloader, pxe, tftp, syslinux

I am looking to integrate provisioning by PXE-booting from a RedHat Satellite Server with a Windows Deployment Server.

To do that, I want the (non-UEFI) syslinux bootloader from WDS to load another EFI boot loader (grub2/grubx64.efi) instead of a Linux kernel. This should be loaded via TFTP as the to-be-provisioned system does not yet have any boot loader installed on the hard disk.

Is that possible?

Background:

In an ideal Satellite-only setting, the Satellite Server likes to have control over DHCP to set its own next-server and file options. It then loads one of the PXE bootloaders by TFTP, which in turn launches the kernel. The Satellite Server would manipulate the DHCP server to set the correct boot loader (in our case, always the same, grub2/grubx64.efi), and also to set the correct kernel arguments that grub would use.

We have a mixed environment, and our DHCP will always point to a syslinux bootloader. I can add something to the syslinux menu, but I cannot replace syslinux.

The naive solution would be to replicate the kernel command line in syslinux, but this does not work because the kernel command line is different for each host (it includes the MAC address).

Therefore, I need a way to get syslinux to then load the grub2/grubx64.efi loader instead, which would then kick off the rest of the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
non-UEFI XXX -> UEFI YYY
```

This not a valid chainload path.

non-UEFI XXX booted in legacy mode then it wont ever be able to chainload to an UEFI YYY component because that component will need the UEFI environment which is missing because you booted legacy.

EDIT 1:

PCs today can boot 2 different pre-boot environments; Legacy (the classic old BIOS environment) or the newer UEFI. You can configure which environment your PC boots by starting your BIOS/Firmware environment and selecting the one you want.

When the PC is also configured to boot from the net it will use the DHCP Discovery packet of the DORA sequence to tell the PXE server which pre-boot environment is being booted then the DHCP server (with PXE enabled) will answer Offering the right NBP (Network boot program) that must be either BIOS or UEFI depending on the previously declared environment.
The PXE chainload process many times involves the loading of a Boot manager and then a boot loader both components must be either Legacy or UEFI but you cannot mixed them up.

Comment: Thank you! Could you elaborate what exactly this UEFI environment is, and where it comes from, since it seems to already be in place at the beginning of the boot process?